# Drawables linking failed after deleting unused file

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I deleted a vector asset which was being used and the created another one with the same name. then all the drable resources are failing to load while files are still there.it ruined my whole project.

I tride Invalidate cache,clean and rebuild project etc. but nothing worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you didn't use the safe delete.

First try to go back to previous asset that was working. If you have source control like Git in your project, just go revert your vector asset file.

If you don't we will revert it by **local history maintained in Android Studio**,

Select the Vector asset file, click on Local history and then click show history.
Now **revert to asset file before deletion.**

[image]

**After this try to build your project project. It should work.**

Comment: thanks , found the issue, somehow there was another xml version daclaration added in one of xml files. surprisingly android studio didn't highlight error this time